# Professional way to initialize an empty string in c++

Tags: c++, string, c++14

Hi I want to learn a professional way to initialize an emtpy string in c++.

I could do

```
std::string a_string;  // way_1
```

or

```
std::string a_string = "";  // way_2
```

But I think `way_1` is fully depending on the default value defined in `std` package. To me, it is not an explicit declaration, and it might need to be changed if the codes of std::string is changed in the future. `way_2` to me is not directly but using `""` which is equivalent to an empty string. To me, a built-in empty string is professional, like `nullptr` for initializing a pointer.

Do you know how would C++ professional programmers initialize an empty string?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this interesting post about empty strings: https://survex.com/~olly/blog/coding/empty-strings-in-c%2B%2B.html

Comment: There is no such thing as "std package". The string class is a part of the standard library defined in the language standard. The default value of the string is defined in the language standard. If you don't trust the standard, don't use the language.

Comment: If I wanted to provide an explicit initializer for an empty string, I would use `{}`: `std::string a_string{};` or `std::string a_string = {};` or `auto a_string = std::string{};`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But I think `way_1` is fully depending on the default value defined in `std` package. To me, it is not an explicit declaration, and it might need to be changed if the codes of `std::string` is changed in the future.

This is faulty reasoning. The default value of `std::string` is defined by the C++ standard and is just as stable as every other part of the language. If you are worried about it changing, then you should also be worrying about `std::string` disappearing completely, or the meaning of `""` changing, or the meaning of the initialization with the empty string changing.

If you are going for "professional", then I, if I saw a programmer using the explicit form, would wonder whether this programmer doesn't know what the default initialization of such a fundamental type as `std::string` does, and therefore what *else* this programmer might not know.